# MvcSiteMapProvider com ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Então, estou tentando montar um menu através de requisições ajax usando também o MvcSiteMapProvider, porém quando tento acessar o meu `CurrentNode` na minha requisição ajax, está dando como `null`

Minha requisição ajax

```
$.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("MenuVisoes", "Menu", new { area = ""})',
                contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html'
            })
                .success(function (result) {
                    $('#menuVisoes').html(result);
                });
        });
```

Minha action

```
public ActionResult MenuVisoes()
        {

            var currentNode = MenuHelper.GetCurrentNode(MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.GetSiteMap());
            //buscar no banco os submenus para o centro de trabalho atual

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView("_MenuVisoes", dados);
            }
            else
            {
                return View("_MenuVisoes", dados);
            } 
        }
```

já tentei pegar o `CurrentNode` assim também `MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.Current.CurrentNode`, mas está sempre retornando nulo
Porém, se ponho dessa forma na minha view, ele mostra certo o meu nó atual.